# Google Cloud DataStore Clarification

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I know appengine datastore and what is cloud datastore, using cloud datastore is always an confusion for me, following are my questions:

1. does cloud datastore requires Compute Engine ?
   (in google docs i saw like enable compute engine)
2. **how to access cloud datastore from appengine application** (this is very needed)
3. how to enable multiple application to access this common datastore ?

Note: I know how to activate it, but I didn't get clear answers for my questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast, i can able to access from cloud datastore from appengine application, following are my answer,

**Ans For Ques 1:**

Cloud Datstore doesn't require compute engine instance.

**Ans for Ques 2:**

To access cloud datastore, you need either service account credentials or u must have access token for authenticated user with Scopes set to Datastore, and user email.

Use Google api Client library,or simply use ProtoBuf library provided in documentation.

**Ans for Ques 3:**

simply use create credentials from application u want to access and use it in other applications

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/overview

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

1) No, cloud datastore can also be user by [other platforms](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_from_other_platforms)

2) App engine has native support to use the (cloud) [datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/). The cloud datastore is based on the App Engine datastore to make it available for others.

3) You can share the cloud datastore, but see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300)

Comment: i knew that activating for other platform, but i dont know how to use it from appengine, also for your second answer, are you talking about cloud datastore, appengine specific impl is for appengine datastore only i think, cloud datastore implementation is different right?, correct me if am wrong

for your 3th answer, that issue is for appengine datastore, its irrelevant i think

Comment: YEs. But it should be posibble to use the cloud datastore when you use app engine to share you datastore.

Comment: ya i know we can access cloud datastore, but i just dont know how

Comment: Update: here: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate you can find the info to use an existing app engine datastore from compute engine or another platform

Comment: ya i have created client id too, but where should i use the client id? which api to use, either to use protobuf or json api ? have you tried it ?

Comment: I do not understand. You can use the datastore in you app engine app. See the app engine docs. This app engine datastore can be used in another NON app engine app on compute engine or another platform using the cloud datastore API. So, whats the question. I did not use it yet.

Comment: Hey voscausa, i dont think i can explain anything better, i know to use **appengine datastore not cloud datastore (both are different)**, cloud datastore is not part of any appengine right, the example given there was to use from compute engine, or access from another platform using json api, my question to be very clear , i want to use Cloud DataStore in appengine (not appengine datastore), if you are clear, it would be very helpful if you could point me to some clear example. thanks!